# How to output projects to different directories when a solution is built?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have multiple solutions and in those solutions there are multiple projects. when I build the the solutions they go to a common directory. I want 2 projects in one of the solutions to output to a different sub-directory and all other projects to the common directory.

How can I do this?

Comment: In the title we should not put the tags, that's what the tags field is for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set the "Output Location" to "AsConfigured", which will put the files in the standard folder which is defined in the project files (defaults to the `bin\$(Configuration)` under the project folder.

You'd then need to call a post-build script (you can create a powershell script and check it into source control) which copies all the files to the output location.

This is [explained in this topic on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#output). An [example script is shown on this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx#scripts). It [can be downloaded here](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1).